# How to set different arrays as minor index for dataframe with pandas multiindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mean, hierarchical-data, multi-index

Two q's:

1) Is it possible to create a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame with different "minor" indices e.g.:

```
   Col1   Col2   
0
    a  0.1    0.01
    b  0.2    0.02
    c  0.3    0.03
1
    m  0.8    0.00
    n  0.9    0.01
    v  0.7    0.10
```

When using Pandas MultiIndex I can only manage to set the the same minor index for all major indices. I wish to know if there is a way to specify different arrays, all of the same length, as minor indices?

2) Say the minor indices (a, b, c, m, n, v) were floats. Is there a way to use pandas mean method to average these values? Until now I can only average data that are not specified as indices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.

Create Multilevel index data:

```
array = list(zip([0]*3,list('abc')))+list(zip([1]*5,list('vwxyz')))
array
```

output:

```
[(0, 'a'),
 (0, 'b'),
 (0, 'c'),
 (1, 'v'),
 (1, 'w'),
 (1, 'x'),
 (1, 'y'),
 (1, 'z')]
```

Use pd.MutliIndex to create index and create a dataframe:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(array,names=['one','two'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':np.random.random(8),'Col2':np.random.random(8)*10},index=idx)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
             Col1      Col2
one two                    
0   a    0.747933  3.191390
    b    0.020055  1.726661
    c    0.342344  5.595333
1   v    0.298349  5.136354
    w    0.445190  3.952943
    x    0.921896  7.905128
    y    0.782851  0.132475
    z    0.259996  9.938946
```

Do overall mean:

```
df.mean()
```

output:

```
Col1    0.477327
Col2    4.697404
dtype: float64
```

Do mean by 'one':

```
print(df.groupby(level=0).mean())
```

Output:

```
         Col1      Col2
one                    
0    0.370111  3.504461
1    0.541656  5.413169
```

Comment: That's it. Hooray!

Comment: 'Col1':np.random.random(8) should be 1D array, what f want multi-dimensional arrays here instead?

Comment: @Giammi, I don't understand.  Can  you pose a new question with your inputs and desired results?

Comment: Maybe `df=pd.DataFrame( [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']],  index = [1,2])`  Using a dataframe constructor like this instead?

Comment: I will try here first: I successfully create an idx `pd.MultiIndex` of 2 columns with 72 tuples as an index. I then try `pd.DataFrame({'Object':OBJ},index=df)` where `OBJ.shape` is (72,24,12). I'd like to store 72 matrixes with dimensions (24,12) from OBJ into a `DataFrame` / `MultiIndexDataFrame` indexed according to idx for rearrangment purposes. I get the error `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`.

Comment: Just try this `df = pd.DataFrame(OBJ, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(listoftuples))`